# Errors with iptables/ipset (operation not permitted) while trying to block Chinese IPs

Tags: iptables

I'm not very experienced trying to do things like this, but I have been wanting to ban Chinese IPs from my VPS running Ubuntu (12.04 32-bit).

I followed this guide, taking the time to read the explanations and not just pasting in whatever it said: https://mattwilcox.net/web-development/unexpected-ddos-blocking-china-with-ipset-and-iptables/

When I got to the part almost at the end about running /etc/block-china.sh I got a long output of the same error repeating: **ipset v6.11: Kernel error received: Operation not permitted**

I have searched and couldn't find any help. Is this something I shouldn't even be attempting to do myself, because of my inexperience? Or is there something that I'm just missing?

Also, I have fail2ban setup and it seems to be working well, should I just settle with using that alone?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the script with privileges? Operation not permitted is usually a need for more privileges. It is a Kernel error so you either need to be root or have kernel permissions to do this. (I forget the name of the kernel permission that would be required)

```
sudo /etc/block-china.sh
```

or

```
su -c 'sh /etc/block-china.sh'
```

Comment: I orginally used sudo, and just tried it again with the same error. The second option you suggested gave me a "**su: Authentication failure**". I will try to find something on kernel permission.

Comment: Also tried with root and got the same error. So does that mean it wouldn't be a kernel permission problem if root still gets the error?